# How to change this flipbook?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

Hello to all who want to help me.

I have a flipbook made with different javascript libraries, in this case they are these:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="extras/jquery.min.1.7.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="extras/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="extras/modernizr.2.5.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/hash.js"></script>
```

Well, to be honest I haven't handled any of these libraries and I don't know much about Jquery, the flipbook is built like this:

```
    <div id="canvas">

<div class="zoom-icon zoom-icon-in"></div>

<div class="magazine-viewport">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="magazine">
            <!-- Next button -->
            <div ignore="1" class="next-button"></div>
            <!-- Previous button -->
            <div ignore="1" class="previous-button"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <div id="slider-bar" class="turnjs-slider">
            <div id="slider"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function loadApp() {

    $('#canvas').fadeIn(1000);

    var flipbook = $('.magazine');

    // Check if the CSS was already loaded

    if (flipbook.width()==0 || flipbook.height()==0) {
        setTimeout(loadApp, 10);
        return;
    }

    // Create the flipbook

    flipbook.turn({

            // Magazine width

            width: 922,

            // Magazine height

            height: 600,

            // Duration in millisecond

            duration: 1000,

            // Enables gradients

            gradients: true,

            // Auto center this flipbook

            autoCenter: true,

            // Elevation from the edge of the flipbook when turning a page

            elevation: 50,

            // The number of pages

            pages: 20,

            // Events

            when: {
                turning: function(event, page, view) {

                    var book = $(this),
                    currentPage = book.turn('page'),
                    pages = book.turn('pages');

                    // Update the current URI

                    Hash.go('page/' + page).update();

                    // Show and hide navigation buttons

                    disableControls(page);

                },

                turned: function(event, page, view) {

                    disableControls(page);

                    $(this).turn('center');

                    $('#slider').slider('value', getViewNumber($(this), page));

                    if (page==1) { 
                        $(this).turn('peel', 'br');
                    }

                },

                missing: function (event, pages) {

                    // Add pages that aren't in the magazine

                    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++)
                        addPage(pages[i], $(this));

                }
            }

    });

    // Zoom.js

    $('.magazine-viewport').zoom({
        flipbook: $('.magazine'),

        max: function() { 

            return largeMagazineWidth()/$('.magazine').width();

        }, 

        when: {
            swipeLeft: function() {

                $(this).zoom('flipbook').turn('next');

            },

            swipeRight: function() {

                $(this).zoom('flipbook').turn('previous');

            },

            resize: function(event, scale, page, pageElement) {

                if (scale==1)
                    loadSmallPage(page, pageElement);
                else
                    loadLargePage(page, pageElement);

            },

            zoomIn: function () {

                $('#slider-bar').hide();
                $('.made').hide();
                $('.magazine').removeClass('animated').addClass('zoom-in');
                $('.zoom-icon').removeClass('zoom-icon-in').addClass('zoom-icon-out');

                if (!window.escTip && !$.isTouch) {
                    escTip = true;

                    $('<div />', {'class': 'exit-message'}).
                        html('<div>Press ESC to exit</div>').
                            appendTo($('body')).
                            delay(2000).
                            animate({opacity:0}, 500, function() {
                                $(this).remove();
                            });
                }
            },

            zoomOut: function () {

                $('#slider-bar').fadeIn();
                $('.exit-message').hide();
                $('.made').fadeIn();
                $('.zoom-icon').removeClass('zoom-icon-out').addClass('zoom-icon-in');

                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.magazine').addClass('animated').removeClass('zoom-in');
                    resizeViewport();
                }, 0);

            }
        }
    });

    // Zoom event

    if ($.isTouch)
        $('.magazine-viewport').bind('zoom.doubleTap', zoomTo);
    else
        $('.magazine-viewport').bind('zoom.tap', zoomTo);


    // Using arrow keys to turn the page

    $(document).keydown(function(e){

        var previous = 37, next = 39, esc = 27;

        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case previous:

                // left arrow
                $('.magazine').turn('previous');
                e.preventDefault();

            break;
            case next:

                //right arrow
                $('.magazine').turn('next');
                e.preventDefault();

            break;
            case esc:

                $('.magazine-viewport').zoom('zoomOut');    
                e.preventDefault();

            break;
        }
    });

    // URIs - Format #/page/1 

    Hash.on('^page\/([0-9]*)$', {
        yep: function(path, parts) {
            var page = parts[1];

            if (page!==undefined) {
                if ($('.magazine').turn('is'))
                    $('.magazine').turn('page', page);
            }

        },
        nop: function(path) {

            if ($('.magazine').turn('is'))
                $('.magazine').turn('page', 1);
        }
    });


    $(window).resize(function() {
        resizeViewport();
    }).bind('orientationchange', function() {
        resizeViewport();
    });

    // Regions

    if ($.isTouch) {
        $('.magazine').bind('touchstart', regionClick);
    } else {
        $('.magazine').click(regionClick);
    }

    // Events for the next button

    $('.next-button').bind($.mouseEvents.over, function() {

        $(this).addClass('next-button-hover');

    }).bind($.mouseEvents.out, function() {

        $(this).removeClass('next-button-hover');

    }).bind($.mouseEvents.down, function() {

        $(this).addClass('next-button-down');

    }).bind($.mouseEvents.up, function() {

        $(this).removeClass('next-button-down');

    }).click(function() {

        $('.magazine').turn('next');

    });

    // Events for the next button

    $('.previous-button').bind($.mouseEvents.over, function() {

        $(this).addClass('previous-button-hover');

    }).bind($.mouseEvents.out, function() {

        $(this).removeClass('previous-button-hover');

    }).bind($.mouseEvents.down, function() {

        $(this).addClass('previous-button-down');

    }).bind($.mouseEvents.up, function() {

        $(this).removeClass('previous-button-down');

    }).click(function() {

        $('.magazine').turn('previous');

    });


    // Slider

    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        min: 1,
        max: numberOfViews(flipbook),

        start: function(event, ui) {

            if (!window._thumbPreview) {
                _thumbPreview = $('<div />', {'class': 'thumbnail'}).html('<div></div>');
                setPreview(ui.value);
                _thumbPreview.appendTo($(ui.handle));
            } else
                setPreview(ui.value);

            moveBar(false);

        },

        slide: function(event, ui) {

            setPreview(ui.value);

        },

        stop: function() {

            if (window._thumbPreview)
                _thumbPreview.removeClass('show');

            $('.magazine').turn('page', Math.max(1, $(this).slider('value')*2 - 2));

        }
    });

    resizeViewport();

    $('.magazine').addClass('animated');

}

// Zoom icon

 $('.zoom-icon').bind('mouseover', function() { 

    if ($(this).hasClass('zoom-icon-in'))
        $(this).addClass('zoom-icon-in-hover');

    if ($(this).hasClass('zoom-icon-out'))
        $(this).addClass('zoom-icon-out-hover');

 }).bind('mouseout', function() { 

     if ($(this).hasClass('zoom-icon-in'))
        $(this).removeClass('zoom-icon-in-hover');

    if ($(this).hasClass('zoom-icon-out'))
        $(this).removeClass('zoom-icon-out-hover');

 }).bind('click', function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass('zoom-icon-in'))
        $('.magazine-viewport').zoom('zoomIn');
    else if ($(this).hasClass('zoom-icon-out')) 
        $('.magazine-viewport').zoom('zoomOut');

 });

 $('#canvas').hide();


// Load the HTML4 version if there's not CSS transform

yepnope({
    test : Modernizr.csstransforms,
    yep: ['lib/turn.min.js'],
    nope: ['lib/turn.html4.min.js', 'css/jquery.ui.html4.css'],
    both: ['lib/zoom.min.js', 'css/jquery.ui.css', 'js/magazine.js', 'css/magazine.css'],
    complete: loadApp
});

</script>
```

This is a flipbook that was passed to me to be able to modify it but I don't know how to do it, the only thing I can change is the number of pages that are going to be shown.

But what I really need help with is if I can change the flipbook to a single page and have them display from page to page (if possible with the same animation when changing the page) and also change the arrows to turn the pages.

I hope you understand me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the part of the code where the flipbook is loaded, this is a turn.js library, so the images or the pdf loading is in the magazine.js file in the loadLargePage and loadSmallPage functions.

In any case a better alternative would be using https://heyzine.com where you can convert the PDF to flipbook and download the code which will look pretty similar but with an easier customization.